# Handle large JSON with Scala

Tags: json, scala, playframework, stack-overflow

I have several files with an array inside and I need to concatenate these arrays. The problem is those files are a lot and quite big (around 5mb each, in total more than 100mb).
I tried with PlayJson but I got back a StackOverflow error and I think this is caused by the parsing of the String into the Json Object, so I am looking for another Scala library. Do you have any suggestion? 
I don't care too much for this case to marshal the json to an object, I simply need a way to do some simple changes in the JSON structure.

Comment: More than a _library_ I would suggest you to try **streaming**. I am not familiar with `PlayJson` but I would expect it to be easily integrated with [`akka-streams`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/) - which I believe will be more natural to you if you are already familiar with _Play & Akka_ - Just to show another  alternative, I would use [`fs2`](https://fs2.io/) for **streaming** and [`circe`](https://circe.github.io/circe/) for **JSON handling**.

Comment: That's an interesting solution, also because the files are on S3, so they are actually a stream. I'll have a look at circe as well. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you can process the data in batches, parallelise the processing, use `Futures`...

Comment: probably akka-streams+alpakka would be really good here, because alpakka provides almost out of the box json streaming and s3 integration

Comment: Do you have control over these files?

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik : yes

Comment: And is your files basically very long array of objects?

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik there is a json obj with several fields. One of those fields is an array and my goal is to concatenate those arrays all together

Comment: why not post the code snippet and the error msg?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Circe + Iteratee or any parser that supports streaming, eg. Jawn.

Here is a very good tutorial for Circe + Iteratee.

https://github.com/circe/circe/tree/main/examples/sf-city-lots

Comment: i have an object that contains a very big list and when i convert it to json i encountered out of memory. I want to encode it using streaming approach and then writ the entire json into a file. How can i proceed